# Taking too much time when getting data from the database, using Promise.each in Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, promise, bluebird

I know this is not a problem with Bluebird library, I am just wondering if I am using the Promises in the right way.

I have 200.000+ records on my MongoDB database, and trying to display those into a table in view. The time it takes now is 30-35 seconds, and I would like this number to decrease to 3-5 seconds if possible or smth like that.

For now this is the code I am using:

```
exports.report = function (req, res) {
var arrayReports = [];
Student.find({ status: role.STUDENT })
    .populate('user')
    .exec(function (err, students) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        Promise.each(students, function (student) {
            return WorksnapsTimeEntry.find({ student: student._id })
                .then(function (doc) {
                    var totalMinutes = 0;
                    var totalAvgLevelActivity = 0;
                    var counter = 0;
                    _.forEach(doc, function (item) {
                        if (item.timeEntries.duration_in_minutes) {
                            totalMinutes = totalMinutes + parseFloat(item.timeEntries.duration_in_minutes[0]);
                        }

                        if (item.timeEntries.activity_level) {
                            totalAvgLevelActivity = totalAvgLevelActivity + parseFloat(item.timeEntries.activity_level[0]);
                            counter++;
                        }
                    });
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.studentId = student._id;
                    obj.displayName = student.displayName;
                    obj.municipality = student.municipality;
                    obj.totalMinutes = totalMinutes;
                    obj.totalAvgLevelActivity = totalAvgLevelActivity / counter;
                    arrayReports.push(obj);
                });
        }).then(function () {
            res.json(arrayReports);
        });
    });
```

};

Is there anyway that I dont need to use .each can I somehow use Promise.all or could you show me some code how would you do this so it would not take so much time to be executed faster.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds more like a question about "how do I get the data I need out of my database more efficiently" than it is a question about promises.  It does appear that you don't have to serialize your requests because one student query is not dependent upon another.  You may want to use `Promise.map()` and experiment with how high you can set  the concurrency option to get faster results.  But, I suspect that the main issue highest order of magnitude issue is that your database is not structured well to match the type of data you're trying to get out of it.

Comment: Displaying 200K+ records in a table might also become an issue in itself.

Comment: @jfriend00, using Promise.map and puting concurrency:5, it did decrease 5-6 seconds less... thnx.. Regarding the db structure, could you suggest something regarding that?

Comment: I don't know MongoDB myself and for those who do, they would probably need a bunch more info on what data you are storing and how you're retrieving it in order to suggest better ways to store it or query it.  Good database design to best meet the needs of the most important queries is a whole expertise in and of itself - expertise in selecting the right type of database, expertise in using/configuring the particular database being used and expertise in designing the data structure.